# Choosing a subset of a set based on the sum of its elements

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, partitions

How can we choose a subset of a set based on the sum of the elements of the subset?

For instance,

```
n=6
dn=Divisors[n]
sn=DivisorSum[n,#&]
```

Is it possible to choose all the subsets of `dn` such that the sum of the elements of the subsets of `dn<sn/2`?

Comment: Does this give the desired result?  `Select[Subsets@Divisors[n], Total[#] < DivisorSum[n, Identity]/2 &]`

Comment: Yes, I you are right.

Answer (score 8):

```
n = 6
dn = Divisors[n];
sn = DivisorSum[n, # &];
Cases[Subsets[dn], x_ /; Total[x] <= sn/2]
```

Gives

```
 {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {6}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

**Edit**

For `<sn/2` instead, it gives

```
Cases[Subsets[dn], x_ /; Total[x] < sn/2]
(*    {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}} *)
```

Comment: in the OP, the criteria is `<` rather than `<=`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks. Adjusted.